# Getting the result of a Lambda in java

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I was wondering how to refer to the result of a lambda in Java? This is so I can store the results into an `ArrayList`, and then use that for whatever in the future.

The lambda I have is:

```
try {
    Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("."),path -> path.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and inside the `.forEach()` I want to be able to assign each file name to the array in turn, for example, `.forEach(MyArrayList.add(this))`

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use :

```
List<String> myPaths = new ArrayList<>();
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("."), path -> path.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
     .forEach(e -> myPaths.add(e.toString()));
```

Edit :

We can achieve the same in one line using :

```
List<String> myPaths = Files.list(Paths.get("."))
                            .filter(p -> p.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                            .map(Object::toString)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Please also see _Side-effects_ section of [Package java.util.stream Description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). For more efficient execution, you should replace `forEach` by reduction. See Holger's comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve that by `collecting` the result of the `newDirectoryStream` operation :

1. You can `add` the elements in a list as you iterate it but that's not the better way :

   ```
   List<Path> listA = new ArrayList<>();
   Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(""), path -> path.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
        .forEach(listA::add);
   ```
2. You may use another method like `find` which returns a `Stream<Path>` that would be easier to use and collect the elements in a list :

   ```
   List<Path> listB = Files.find(Paths.get(""), 1,(p, b) -> p.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
3. Or `Files.list()`

   ```
   List<Path> listC = Files.list(Paths.get("")).filter(p -> p.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

Comment: Or `List<Path> listC = Files.list(Paths.get("")).filter(p -> p.toString().endsWith(".txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 3):

You can create a variable which represents the current element in `forEach` and refer it, for example:

```
ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();

Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("."), path -> path.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
        .forEach(path -> paths.add(path));
```

which also can be simplied to:

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("."), path -> path.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
        .forEach(paths::add);
```

Comment: Using the method reference paths::add instead of path -> paths.add(path) would be even nicer in my opinion.